# params$ not being recognized in rMarkdown (i.e. case)

Tags: r

I know this isn't reproducible code, but it should give an idea of the issue I'm facing.

I'm using an R script to pass in a parameter to an RMarkdown. i.e. it loops through a dataframe and for each row, that value is passed in as a parameter to the RMarkdown.

**RMarkdown heading:**

```
params:
   case: case
```

**R Script to render RMarkdown based on parameters:**

```
render_flexdash <- function(case, dag_name) {
  # assuming the output format of input.Rmd is PDF
  rmarkdown::render(
    "X:/FlexDashboard_v7.RMD",
    output_file = paste0('X:/HTML/', 'dashboard_',dag_name, '.html'),
    params = list(case=case), 
    envir = parent.frame(),
    rm(list = ls())
  )
}


for (case in redcap_data_access_groups$redcap_data_access_group) {
  dag_name <- (redcap_data_access_groups$redcap_data_access_group_name[redcap_data_access_groups$redcap_data_access_group==case])
  #make the dashboard HTML doc
  render_flexdash(case, dag_name) #pass in the case to the RMarkdown!
  print(case)
}
```

My issue is that up until today, it was working fine, and today, I had an issue where my R Studio Desktop workspace got cleared (i.e. all the files were closed so maybe something got changed in my environment) and now the params$case in my RMarkdown are recognized only sometimes.

For example, the first couple times I call the parameter `params$case` it works as expected and the dataframe is filtered correctly. But if I call `params$case` later on in the script, it does not recognize it.  Nothing in the definition of `params$case` has changed, so I'm not sure why it would work sometimes in the script, and other times is not recognized.

**My RMarkdown:**

```
#This works
totals.filtered.by.parameter <- data %>%
  dplyr::filter(injury_county == params$case) 

#This doesn't work.
totals.filtered.by.parameter.2 <- data.2 %>%
  dplyr::filter(injury_county == params$case)
```